# SceneKit transparency issues on iOS11

Tags: ios, scenekit

I have a simple scene with a rotating sphere. I have set the transparency of the material in order to get the desired look on iOS 10. The problem is that in iOS 11 the material's transparency needs to be (approximately) 10 times smaller in order to get the same effect. I have tried all the transparencyModes, setting the transparency programatically or using XCode editor, setting the opacity and got the same result.

I didn't found anything in the Apple documentation about this situation.

I can fix this by setting different transparency values depending on the iOS version but i would like to know why is this happening

Comment: Can you provide screenshots of the results you are seeing in iOS 10 and in iOS 11? Since you don't have permission to upload and embed images yet, I'd suggest uploading the images elsewhere and updating your questions with links to the two images.

Comment: Are you using OpenGL or Metal as the rendering api for Scenekit?